# change regex to accept $,% and & VB.NET 2010

Tags: regex, vb.net-2010

I have a function to accept
Strings like

```
VECJ`880326`AB1
ROPL`951201`HD9
ABC`680504`XXX
```

But I want to accept also

```
V&CJ`880326`AB1
RO%L`951201`HD9
ABC$`680504`XXX
```

How would I change the function:

```
Function IsValid(ByVal strIn As String) As Boolean
  Return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, ("^[a-zA-Z]{3,4}(\d{6})((\D|\d){3})?$"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you already have a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Simply add the required characters:

```
"^[a-zA-Z$%&]{3,4}(\d{6})((\D|\d){3})?$"
```

Also, are you aware that you accepting **any** 3 characters at the end? `\d` is any digit character, and `\D` is any other character. If you meant to accept only letters and digits, you could use `[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}` instead of `(\D|\d){3}`.